# "npm install -g npm@latest" corrupted my npm installation - Windows 8.1

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

Last month I installed node 10.16.3 LTS and because it didn't have latest npm version I've updated it using this official guide: https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm (option 2):

1. removed both **%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\npm** and 
   **%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\npm.cmd**
2. moved 'npmrc' file from **%ProgramFiles%\nodejs\node_modules\npm** to **%appdata%\npm\node_modules\npm**

Today, after I've installed 'create-react-app', npm showed me message that new minor version of npm is available 6.11.3 -> 6.12.0 and that I can update it.

I ran 'npm install -g npm@latest' but that just threw me bunch of errors:

```
C:\Users\Wladyslaw\AppData\Roaming\npm\npx -> C:\Users\Wladyslaw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npx-cli.js
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Wladyslaw\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Wladyslaw\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Wladyslaw\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Users\Wladyslaw\AppData\Roaming\npm\npm'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!      path: 'C:\\Users\\Wladyslaw\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\npm' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open \'C:\\Users\\Wladyslaw\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\npm\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Wladyslaw\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\npm' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Wladyslaw\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-10-17T19_35_58_442Z-debug.log
```

Now I can't even run 'npm -v', it somehow removed my npm folder and just showing me this message:

```
bash: /c/Users/Wladyslaw/AppData/Roaming/npm/npm: No such file or directory
```

Is there any way to repair such damaged npm installation without reinstalling whole Node.js?

Thank you

Comment: So I had to completely reinstall Node.js. Apparently mentioned above guide is slightly outdated. Newest Node installer doesn't put 'C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs' on PATH at all, only 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm'. Just ran same 'npm install -g npm@latest' and now I have latest npm

Answer (score 1):

You have just run the command line as administrator

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Though it may be possible to try to "fix" your setup, it's not really worth it, you however don't want to lose your installed packages I presume. So:

- Make a temp folder `C:\Users\Wladyslaw\AppData\Roaming\npm.temp`
- Move `C:\Users\Wladyslaw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules` to `<temp_folder>`
- Move `C:\Users\Wladyslaw\AppData\Roaming\npm\*.bat` to `<temp_folder>`
- Move `C:\Users\Wladyslaw\AppData\Roaming\npm\*.cmd` to `<temp_folder>`
- Install node from installer (https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
- Move back each folder and file from `<temp_folder>` into `C:\Users\Wladyslaw\AppData\Roaming\npm`

  - Don't overwrite any files!

### Powershell Scripts

Haven't tested it since I have a non-traditional installation using [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). But these should do what I wrote above, so here goes:

***backup.ps1***

```bsh
pushd $Env:AppData
$NF = 'npm.temp'
md $NF -ea SilentlyContinue | Out-Null # Make folder, if exists, don't cry about it
mv npm/node_modules $NF                # Back up node modules
$GlobalPacks = ls npm | ? Name -Match '\.(cmd|bat)$|\.npmrc' # Only select bat / cmd files or your .npmrc file
cp $GlobalPacks $NF
Write-Host -f 2 '[+] Backed up data to $NF'
```

Now install Node.js from the website, then run:

***restore.ps1***

```bsh
pushd $Env:AppData
$NF = 'npm.temp'
if (!(Test-Path $NF)) {
  Write-Host -f Red "[-] Could not find backup folder, are you sure you backed up?"
  exit
}
cp npm/node_modules $NF -re -fo   # Overwrite backup modules with new files
if (!$?) {Write-Host -f yellow "[!] Something failed";exit}
rm npm/node_modules
mv "$NF/node_modules" npm         # Bring all node_modules to npm
ls $NF -File | % {mv $_ npm}      # Move global package scripts
Write-Host -f 2 '[+] Restored from [$NF] -> [$pwd\npm]'
```